# Autodesk Maya 2016 Crashes on startup in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, crash, error-handling, 3d

My PC Details

> RAM = 8 GB
>
> Processor = Intel® Core™ i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
>
> Graphics = GeForce GTX 650/PCIe/SSE2
>
> Graphics Driver = 367.18
>
> OS = [x64 bit] Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

After successfully installing Autodesk Maya 2016 on my pc, Now its crashing. duh.
[image]